# Fastest string searching algorithm for fixed text and a lot of substrings

Tags: c, string, performance, substring

I am trying to find an algorithm to search for binary strings of fixed size (64 bit) in a large binary buffer (100 MB). The buffer is always the same and i have got lots and lots of strings to search for (2^500 maybe). 
I have to find all the occurrences of any given string, not only the first one.

What algorithm can i choose from? Maybe one that benefits from the constant buffer in which i search.

Links to C source code for such algorithm is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string are 8-bit aligned, from 100MB buffer you'll get 100 millions different strings, which can be put into the hash table approximately 800MB in size with constant (O(1)) access time.

This will allow you to make the search as fast as possible, because once you have your 8 byte string, you immediately know where this string was seen in your buffer.

Comment: if i want to search for strings of 64 bytes does this still apply? I should have less possible substrings right?

Comment: @RoccoMancin it does not matter, if you have 100MB buffer, you'll get (100e6-64) of 64 byte strings, or (100e6-8) of 8 byte strings, all in all it's approximately 100e6 strings.